Inspector Gadget on public television?
A long time ago (I'm guessing late 1970s or early 1980s) I happened upon an animated motion-picture on my local public-television station (which was probably KPBS in the Los Angeles area). During the opening credits, there was some operatic singing, coming from a wrapped object floating on the ocean waves.  As the credits ended, it washed up on the shore, a young girl found it and unwrapped it, and it was a parrot in a cage.  The rest of the movie involved her and several other talking animals as they looked for some sort of missing object, which was found by the end.  During the pledge breaks, the show was referred to as Inspector Gadget, e.g. "Inspector Gadget will be right back after these messages", even though he himself never showed up in the movie.
I've never been able to find any evidence that this movie ever existed.  The existing Inspector Gadget made-for-TV animated movies happened much later, and don't have this plot.  But in retrospect, the young girl was certainly a match for Penny.
Does anyone have any idea what this was?

Either there's no connection or it would have had to be later than you remember. The animated series didn't start until 1983 and the Wiki article seems to imply that it's original.

I don't suppose you're misremembering the title?
It sounds like it could be this film, The Talking Parcel.

The Talking Parcel (also published as The Battle for Castle Cockatrice) is a 1974 book by Gerald Durrell in which children are transported to the fantasy land of Mythologia to save it from cockatrices. They are aided by a talking parrot and encounter many other magical creatures, including a mooncalf.

It has a talking parrot as the main character alongside a girl named Penelope, who is blonde, similar to Penny from Inspector Gadget.

It was made into an animated feature for television by Cosgrove Hall Films in 1978, debuting on ITV. However, the film differs from the book mainly by introducing only one human protagonist, the girl Penelope.

From the IMDb description, it sounds pretty much identical to what you've described:

A wrapped parcel is seen floating on the sea (Song: "Mooncarrot Pie") towards a shore where a young girl, Penelope (Lisa Norris) is playing. Unwrapping it, she discovers The Parrot (Freddie Jones) who enlists her to return with him to Mythologia to rescue its rightful ruler, the wizard H. H. Junketberry (Edward Kelsey) from the dungeons of the Chief Cockatrice (Windsor Davis) and his minions.

Here's a video of the trailer:




It sure looks like the same movie. I don't know how Inspector Gadget got into that memory, but then, a few neurons could have decayed in 30 years. In any case, I've ordered myself a copy.  Thanks!
